# Unable to ajax file upload with jQuery 1.9.1 and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a file upload form that uploads directory to Amazon S3 with a generated policy. Works fine with jQuery <=1.9.0 but broken in 1.9.1 and up and I can't figure out why.  With 1.9.0 it returns a status of 'success' and the data object is there. With 1.9.1 it immedialtely returns 'nocontent' - status code is 204 and data object is undefined.  Here's the changelog for 1.9.1 - There is something about serializing forms but reading it hasn't made anything click in me. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/

Here's the basics of the form:

```
$('.inputFile').on('change', function () {
var data = new FormData();
var t = $('#uploads');
var r;

$('.fileupload').spin({ left: '120px', lines: 8, length: 4, width: 3, radius: 5, top: '5px' });

requestCredentials = function(file) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/image/policy?file=" + file.name,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(res) {

      data.append('key', res.key);
      data.append('bucket', res.bucket);
      data.append('AWSAccessKeyId', res.aws_key);
      data.append('acl', res.acl);
      data.append('success_action_redirect', res.redirect);
      data.append('Content-Type', res.content_type);
      data.append('policy', res.policy);
      data.append('signature',  res.signature);
      data.append('file', file);

      $.ajax({
        url: res.endpoint,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
          console.log('I am jquery 1.9.0');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.log('I am jquery 1.9.1');
        }
      });

    },
    error: function(res, status, error) {
      console.log('Whoops');
    }
  });
};
$.each($(this).get(0).files, function(i, file) {
  requestCredentials(file);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug on jquery's part, see here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13292

This bug has since been fixed, so it should work on the latest version of jquery.